# Images is shown crashed in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, crash, oracle-apex

I have created table with blob field to upload images [My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvSAy.jpg)

I uploaded images successfully to it.

When creating classic report, images are shown crashed [Photo Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTL1j.jpg)

I used this code in PL/SQL query to show it:

```
select STAFF_ALL_CODE,
   STAFF_IMAGE ,
   decode(nvl(dbms_lob.getlength(STAFF_IMAGE),0),
            0,
            null,
            '<a href="'||apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P4_IMAGE',STAFF_ALL_CODE)||'">'||'<img src="'
            ||apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P4_IMAGE',STAFF_ALL_CODE)||'" height="200" width="200" />'
            ||'</a>'
        )  Download 
from ALL_STAFF_IMAGE
```

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Open the browser console and look for errors. You ORDS configuration may be incomplete. I presume page 4 is a separate page, and is still operational?

Comment: I am beginner with oracle apex , can you give more details please?

Comment: I'm referring to the *browser* console, detailed here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/ it may indicate files that failed to load in a web page

Answer (score 0):

This is how I display images (somewhat simpler than you); try to use it:

```
DECODE (
        NVL (DBMS_LOB.getlength (staff_image), 0),
        0, NULL,
           '<img src="'
        || APEX_UTIL.get_blob_file_src ('P4_IMAGE', staff_all_code)
        || '" width="150" />')
        photo
```

`P4_IMAGE` should be a "File browse" item whose storage type is "BLOB column specified in item source attribute"; basically, if you use an item you use to upload images into the database, it should be OK.